# 500 server error on ajax calls in typo3 using Eid

Tags: ajax, typo3, dispatcher, extbase

I'm trying to grab some data from the database on a page in typo3 using Ajax . So after a long time looking for the appropriate way to do it , I got convinced that The Ajax Dispatcher is the best tool to do the job . So I created the file following the instructions to be found here.

Now when I make an Ajax call on my page , the console displays a 500 (Internal Server Error).

joined is a snapshot of my console tab.

and this is the jquery function that gets run on an onchange event .

function getContent(id) {

```
console.log("Start process ...");
$.ajax({
           async: 'true',
           url: 'index.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
               eID: "ajaxDispatcher",
               request: {
                   pluginName:  'listapp',
                   controller:  'Pays',
                   action:      'getMyCos',
                   arguments: {
                       'id': id,
                              }
                       }
           },
           dataType: "json",

           success: function(result) {
               console.log(result);
           },
           error: function(error) {
               console.log(error);
           }
       });
```

}
Could someone please help me , I just started developing with this CMS of shit :p

[image]

Comment: You should get better error messages if you are logged in to the backend while the request is done. Also, check the PHP error log.

Comment: well concerning the error log file , I've just checked it again and it's empty , as for the other tip you gave , I didn't really understand what you meant .

Comment: Log into the TYPO3 backend (as admin? not sure), and trigger that failing AJAX request while you are logged in. You should get a much nicer error message, not only "Oops, an error occurred". You can also try to use the configuration preset "development" in the install tool, which is available as of TYPO3 6.2.

Comment: well , I activated the development mode , but no errors would be shown , in addition , the ajax call i;m trying to make is in the Front End and more exactly on a view ... I have 2 controllers for an extension I created myself , Countrys and Companys , on the list Action for Countrys , countries are listed in a select item , on a change event on that select i want to list out all the companys that belong to each country ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the file AjaxDispatcher :

line 101 to: `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::getInstance();`